# Windows 11: How to disable MiniSearchHost permanently to avoid clear square on screen?

Tags: windows, windows-11, bug

I want to disable MiniSearchHost **permanently**.

I'm facing a bug that bothers me a lot. A weird clear square on the screen that says loading when I hover over it pops up each time I turn on my computer and use it a little while.

[image]

I've found out it is because of `MiniSearchHost.exe`. So every time this bug shows up I have to go to the `details` tap of the `task manager` and find `MiniSearchHost.exe` to end task it.
I want to know if I can turn it off permanently and avoid it even running from the beginning so I don't have to kill it every time.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11/661b282f-dfdb-4304-83d2-da1db7acfe94

Comment: https://geekermag.com/fix-transparent-floating-box-above-taskbar-in-windows-11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only permanent workaround seems to be to remove the
"magnifying glass" from the Taskbar:

Right-click Taskbar => Taskbar settings => turn off "Search".

After doing that, you will need to run searches through the search bar
at the top of the Start menu.

Other workarounds might be found in the future, or Microsoft may fix the
bug sometime.

Comment: Thank you! this helps too.